# Vanishing of finite difference operators by composition under a cyclic condition

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-algebras

Consider $n$ finite difference operators $D_1, \ldots, D_n$
acting on real-valued functions $f_1 (y), \ldots , f_n (y)$ 
of a variable $y$, with the following properties:

(i) $D_i f_i (y) = 0$ for all $y$ and $i=1,\ldots , n$,

(ii) Commutation relation: $D_i D_j = D_j D_i$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots , n$,

(iii) Finite difference product rule:
$$
  D_i ( fg ) = f D_i g + g D_i f + D_i f D_i g, \qquad
  i=1,\ldots , n. 
$$ 
(iv) Cyclic vanishing condition:
$$ 
( D_{i_1} f_{i_2} ) \times ( D_{i_2} f_{i_3} ) \times \cdots \times ( D_{i_{m-1}} f_{i_m} ) \times ( D_{i_m} f_{i_1} ) = 0, 
$$ 
 for all sequences $i_1,\ldots ,i_m \in \{ 1, \ldots , n \}$ 
 and all $m \geq 1$.

We would like to prove that
$$ 
{\bf  D_1 \cdots D_n ( f_1 \cdots f_n ) = 0} \qquad \qquad (1) 
$$ 
 for all $n\geq 1$.
 The cases $n=1,2,3$ are treated below by hand computation.

More generally, can (1) be proved for all $n\geq 1$
 in an automated way, using a symbolic computing tool/language,
 based on the above conditions (i)-(ii)-(iii)-(iv) ?

For example, is there a way  to completely expand
$$ 
D_1 \cdots D_n(f_1 \cdots f_n)
$$ 
according to the finite difference chain rule (iii),
by taking into account the cycling vanishing condition (ii) automatically ?

Case $n=1$. Clearly, (1) holds for $n=1$ by (i) above.

Case $n=2$. We have 
\begin{align*} 
D_1D_2(f_1f_2) & =  D_1 ( f_1 D_2 f_2 + f_2 D_2 f_1 + D_2 f_2 D_2 f_1 )
\\ 
& =  D_1 ( f_2 D_2 f_1 )   \qquad \qquad [\mbox{because }D_2 f_2 = 0]
\\ 
& = D_1 f_2 D_2 f_1 + f_2 D_1 D_2 f_1 + D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_1
\\ 
& =  D_1 f_2 D_2 f_1 + f_2 D_2 D_1 f_1 + D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_1
\qquad [\mbox{because } D_1 D_2 = D_2 D_1 ]
\\ 
& =  D_1 f_2 D_2 f_1 \qquad [\mbox{because }D_1 f_1 = 0]
\\ 
 & =  0. \qquad \qquad [\mbox{because of the cyclic condition }(iv) \mbox{ for } n=2]
\end{align*} 
Case $n=3$. We now show by hand computation that
$$ 
D_1D_2D_3 (f_1f_2f_3) = 0. 
$$ 
 We have 
\begin{align*} 
& D_1 D_2 D_3 ( f_1 f_2 f_3 ) =  
 D_1 D_2 ( f_3 D_3 ( f_1 f_2 ) ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 D_2 ( f_3 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
 + 
 D_1 D_2 ( f_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 )
 + 
 D_1 D_2 ( f_3 D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_2 f_3 D_2 ( f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( f_1 D_3 f_2 ) ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_2 f_3 D_2 ( f_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( f_2 D_3 f_1 ) )
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_2 f_3 D_2 ( D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 ) ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 ( f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( f_1 D_3 f_2 ) ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_2 f_3 D_2 ( f_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( f_2 D_3 f_1 ) )
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 ( D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 ( D_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 ) ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 f_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_2 f_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 )
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 ( f_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
\\ 
 & 
 + 
 D_1 ( f_2 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 )
\\ 
 &  
 + D_1 ( f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 f_3 D_1 ( D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 ( D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 ( D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_1 ( D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 f_3 D_1 ( D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 ( D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 ( f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 ( f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 ( D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
 + 
 f_3 D_1 ( D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 D_1 f_2 
 + 
 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_1 D_3 f_2 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 D_1 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1  D_1 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 D_1 f_2 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 - 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_2 ( D_2 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 + 
 D_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 - 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_2 D_2 ( D_1 f_3 D_3 f_1 ) 
\\ 
 &  
 + 
 D_1 f_3 D_3 D_2 f_1 D_3 f_2 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 - 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_3 D_2 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 - 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
. 
\end{align*} 
 Now by swapping the indices $1$ and $2$ and reusing 
 the above formula we still have 
\begin{align*} 
 D_1 D_2 D_3 ( f_1 f_2 f_3 ) 
 & =  
 D_2 D_1 D_3 ( f_2 f_1 f_3 ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 D_3 D_1 f_2 
 + 
 D_2 f_1 D_1 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 - 
 D_2 f_1 D_2 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 
. 
\end{align*} 
 Hence 
\begin{align*} 
 ( D_1 D_2 D_3 ( f_1 f_2 f_3 ) )^2 
 & =  
 ( D_1 D_2 D_3 ( f_1 f_2 f_3 ) ) 
 ( D_2 D_1 D_3 ( f_2 f_1 f_3 ) ) 
\\ 
 & =  
 ( D_1 f_3 D_3 f_2 D_3 D_2 f_1 
 + 
 D_1 f_2 D_2 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 - 
 D_1 f_2 D_1 f_3 D_2 D_3 f_1 
 ) 
\\ 
 &  \times 
 ( 
 D_2 f_3 D_3 f_1 D_3 D_1 f_2 
 + 
 D_2 f_1 D_1 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 - 
 D_2 f_1 D_2 f_3 D_1 D_3 f_2 
 )
\\ 
 & =  0, 
\end{align*} 
 where the vanishing is obtained by checking 
 that each of the $9$ cross-product terms 
 vanishes due to the cyclic conditions of orders $2$ and $3$.